# Capitalize all letters before number in string

Tags: javascript

I need to capitalize all letters in the beginning of a string, all letters *before* the first number that appears in the string.

abc123 will be ABC123

abc123def will be ABC123def

First I find the index of the first number in the string:

```
var index = myString.search(/\d/);
```

Then I have a for loop where I try to change every letter before that number:

```
for (var i=0; i<index; i++) {
    myString = myString.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + myString.slice(i+1);
}
```

The problem is that the code removes the letter in the beginning in every loop.
How can I do it better?

Thank you for your help

Comment: `console.log(myString.replace(/^\D+/, s => s.toUpperCase()));`

Comment: What about: `"abcd12efgh34ijkl"`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir "before the first number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by the code below:

```js
var str = "abc23mlk";
var index = str.search(/\d/);
if (index !== -1) {
    str = str.slice(0, index).toUpperCase() + str.slice(index);
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is what I was looking for. Nice and easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex and a replacer function:

```js
function replace(text) {
  return text.replace(/[a-z]+(?=\d)/i, function(match) {
    return match.toUpperCase();
  });
}

["abc123", "abc123def", "abcd12efgh34ijkl"].forEach(function(test) {
  console.log("'" + test + "' becomes '" + replace(test) + "'"); 
});
```

The regex `/[a-z]+(?=\d)/i` looks for the first sequence of letters (`[a-z]+`) that is immediately followed by a digit (`(?=\d)` here as a positive look-ahead so it is not matched).

Answer (score 1):

You also do something like

1. Find the index as how you are doing now
2. Substring and capitalize
3. Slice and append

> ```
> var myString = "abc123"
> var index = myString.search(/\d/);
> myString = myString.substr(0,index).toUpperCase() + myString.slice(index);
> ```